# DateTime Xml Deserialization

Tags: .net, xml, soap

Sorry if this issue has been beaten to death, but I can't seem to find a good answer to my question.

I have written a .NET 2.0 client that consumes a web service.  The web method I call returns several DateTime values in UTC format.

It appears that the values are being deserialized as DateTimeKind.Local.  I assume this is the default behavior for the .NET SOAP framework.  However, I need the values to be DateTimeKind.Unspecified.

What are my options for overriding the deserialization of these DateTime values?

Comment: When the date are serialized, is the Date kind equals to DateTimeKind.Unspecified or DateTimeKind.Local?

Comment: I don't know. I didn't create the web service. I need to change the way they are de-serialized.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I've found on MSDN:

> When using the .NET Framework version
>   1.0 and 1.1, DO NOT send a DateTime value that represents UCT time thru
>   System.XML.Serialization. This goes
>   for Date, Time and DateTime values.
>   For Web services and other forms of
>   serialization to XML involving
>   System.DateTime, always make sure that
>   the value in the DateTime value
>   represents current machine local time.
>   The serializer will properly decode an
>   XML Schema-defined DateTime value that
>   is encoded in GMT (offset value = 0),
>   but it will decode it to the local
>   machine time viewpoint.

I do not know if this is still true for .NET 2.0

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973825.aspx#datetime_topic2a) is the link to the article.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

The DateTime values are *not* being sent in UTC like I thought. They are local times with the time zone offset.

However, my problem still remains: I need the DateTime values to be deserialized without the time zone offset.  I want the times in their local time zone, not converted to my time zone.

I found a work-around, though. It turned out to be pretty easy to write a SoapExtension descendant to remove the time zone information from all xs:dateTime values.